# Javascript password validation with regular expression

Tags: javascript

im trying to validate a password field with the following conditions, if the requirements are meet the password field should change its color to green if not should be red:
One lowercase character
One uppercase character
One number
One special character
Eight characters minimum
i tried with a regular expression but somehow it only makes it red even if i input a password with all the requirements. Any idea?

```
let passwordField = document.getElementById("password");
passwordField.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let checkPass =
    /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
  if (checkPass.test(password.value)) {
    passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    console.log("green");
  } else {
    passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("red");
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: it would be better with a regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx should be:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})
```

Where:

1. lower char = `(?=.*[a-z])`
2. upper char = `(?=.*[A-Z])`
3. 1 number = `(?=.*[0-9])`
4. special char = `(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])`
5. min length to 8 = `(?=.{8,})`

```js
let passwordField = document.getElementById("password");
passwordField.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let checkPass =
    new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");
  if (checkPass.test(password.value)) {
    passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    console.log("green");
  } else {
    passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("red");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="password" />
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: still makes it red

Comment: @EljanoHita check the image in my answer

Comment: @EljanoHita with what password you are trying?

Comment: it should be sth else that im missing in my code because running the code snnipet works fine

Comment: No problem. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this, it is exact same you want**

```js
    let passwordField = document.getElementById("password");
    passwordField.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
      var decimal=  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
      if (passwordField.value.match(decimal)) {
        passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        console.log("green");
      } else {
        passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        console.log("red");
      }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>This is a password validation</h1>
    <input id="password" />

    </body>
    </html>
```